# Why is $(Z^+,\le)$ not a counter example to Zorn's lemma?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Zorn's lemma states that, if X is a partially ordered set such that every chain in X has an upper bound, then X contains a maximal element.

I think that $(Z^+,\le)$ satisfies the conditions of Zorn's lemma. The order is partial and every totally ordered subset has an upper bound in $Z^+$. Yet, since $Z^+$ is infinite, it has no maximal element.

Where is the fault in my reasoning?

Comment: The mistake is the claim that every chain in $Z^+$ has an upper bound. For example $Z^+$ is a chain and has no upper bound.

Comment: Thanks CyclotomicField! I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

$Z^+$ is a totally ordered subset having no upper bound in $Z^+.$

Comment: Yes indeed, I now see my mistake. Thank you!